# Excel formula to sort comma delimited list by word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope you are all well.  I am trying to sort a list of words in excel in a single column that has multiple words separated by a comma in a cell.  I would like an output to be another delimited list sorted by word.  So for example

|  | INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | Word 1, word 6, word 5 | Word 1, Word 5, word 6 |
| Row 2 | word 3, word 9, word 2, word 7 | Word 2, word 3, word 7, word 9 |

I have a list of all the possible words that can be in the delimited lists in a column.  Is there a way to assign a number to the words and then have them organize based off the number?

Thanks,

Comment: If you have Office 365 and Windows you could use a combination of `FILTERXML` (to split the comma separated words) and `SORTBY` (to mention an array to sort by)

Comment: If you do not have Office 365, then you will most likely need to use vba to do this.

Answer (score 0):

@P.b you'll have to let me know if this was what you had in mind. It took me forever to figure out the SORTBY part. There's gotta be a cleaner way.

```
=LET(myarray,FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SORTBY(myarray,INDEX(Table3,MATCH(myarray,Table3[Fruit],0),{2}))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the same set-up and namings as @Bryan Rock, and assuming that *Table3* is fixed so as to be sorted ascendingly on the *Index* column:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH(","&Table3[Fruit]&",",","&A2&",")),Table3[Fruit],""))`